# Split a base64 line into chunks

Tags: string, go, encoding, base64

What is the best way to split a one line base64 into multiple lines by 76 chars. Currently I use `encoding/base64` package as this:

```
encoded := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A loop and slicing operations `[0:76]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for this in the standard lib. You have to make one yourself.

A simple implementation can be like this:

```
func split(s string, size int) []string {
    ss := make([]string, 0, len(s)/size+1)
    for len(s) > 0 {
        if len(s) < size {
            size = len(s)
        }
        ss, s = append(ss, s[:size]), s[size:]

    }
    return ss
}
```

This loops until the string is consumed, and in each iteration cuts of `size` chars (bytes) from the beginning.

Note that this works on base64 texts as that only uses characters which map 1-to-1 to bytes in the UTF-8 encoded form (which is how Go stores strings in memory). If you would want to use this on arbitrary strings, slicing could break valid UTF-8 sequences, and also chunks would not necessarily be `size` characters.

Testing it:

```
s := strings.Repeat("1", 2*76+3)
for _, chunk := range split(s, 76) {
    fmt.Println(chunk)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lsGRJn3B92)):

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
111
```